# iOS - Synchronous Request with Timeout failing

Tags: ios, http, swift, request, synchronous

I have code that looks like this:

```
let urlPath: String = "https://github.com/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json/raw/master/citylots.json"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url, 
                                  cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, 
                              timeoutInterval: 1)

var response:NSURLResponse?;
var error:NSError?;

/*** the follow line is giving the error ***/
var data:NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(
                                                  request1, 
                               returningResponse: &response, 
                                           error: &error)!

if( error != nil) {
    println ("ERROR")
} else {
    println(response)
    self.config = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary)

}
println("Done with Synchronous Request")
```

If the request takes too long, there's a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for the `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(...)` call. I'm not sure what is going on. When I looked at the debug window, the only variable that is `nil` is `response`. This code looks very similar to the examples I've seen across the web.

If the request is finished within the time, no fatal error happens.

I want to be able to catch the timeout error. Anyone know what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the exclamation mark in the wrong place in this line,

```
var data:NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)!
```

It should be,

```
var data:NSData! =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```